# Are there fonts with multiple latin characters in the same glyph?

Tags: fonts, glyph

I'm having a little project where i'm trying to localize a japanese software. Sadly for this project i cannot change the byte length of several strings and they're hardcoded to use UTF16, which means a single kanji that can represent a complicated word can only be replaced with a single latin letter. (As opposed to UTF8, where latin letters use up fewer bytes.)

However the fonts the software uses can be replaced freely.

One solution for this then would be to use a font that has glyphs that contain multiple latin characters.

Does something like this already exist?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "a single kanji [...] can only be replaced with a single latin letter. As opposed to UTF8, where latin letters use up fewer bytes." Those are completely unrelated things. What are you trying to _do_? Why would localization be remotely related to what's in the font? You're translating strings, not faking the text by putting text-as-pictures in a font.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's legacy software and in the process of localizing this particular project i cannot change the byte length of the strings.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans He wants to translate e.g. "水曜日", trying to fit "Wednesday" into the original 6-byte memory location. Under UTF16, you can only fit "Wed" in there, as each letter still takes up 2 bytes. He's asking if there is a font similar to Korean Hanja but Latin, which might have "Wed" in one codepoint, "nes" in another and "day" in a third. I highly doubt it's a feasible approach.

Comment: @Amadan Yes, you understood my desire correctly. Would you elaborate on why you doubt it's feasible?

Comment: For what it's worth, i used the library mentioned here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48695/make-a-character-in-a-font-look-like-multiple-characters-of-the-same-font#comment68784_48699, wrote a script to replace the "o" glyph with "Te", injected the font into the software, replaced a japanese string of 6 characters with "oooooo" and the result is this: https://i.imgur.com/j2YxtCX.png ... Right now that leaves me with the option to cannibalize the Kanji i won't need for an english translation, or try and add to the PUA.

Comment: And now, as [this script](https://gist.github.com/wchristian/11e602022ebde145fbbb8e3d4f4a554e) works, i can just add however many glyphs needed to the PUA then use the script above to cycle through them and add the required character combinations.

Comment: I would recommend against this if you're able to use a normal OpenType font: instead of PUA, use the GSUB mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use an OpenType font: use the GSUB mechanism, which is the most "natural" (insofar as that is a thing) way to localize through a font. By defining every character sequence in your localization map as its own substitution rule, you also avoid overlap problems that you get from a PUA mapping.

First off, you define your font with the normal latin character set you want to use, using a standard cmap subtable format 4 (effectively: like all modern fonts), and then you define the entire CJK space as "supported" by using a cmap subtable format 14 to say "all codepoints between 2E80 and 10FFF0 are supported and map to glyphid 1". Now your font "supports" CJK but it won't actually be able to "draw" CJK text. And that's fine:

you then define (lots of) GSUB many-to-many ligature rules of the form:

```
...
消_す -> d_e_l_e_t_e
ヘ_ル_プ -> h_e_l_p
...
```

so that the true magic happens: without changing *anything* in your actual application other than changing the font, you now get the correct English (or whatever language you need) correspondence strings purely by virtue of the font doing what it's supposed to do: it sees that it needs to shape the string `消す`, goes "I support all the characters in that string", then goes "I have a substitution rule for this exact combination of code points" and then goes "I have shaped the combination for `delete`, here it is."

Of course, this may lead to localizations where your English label is too wide, and you might still need PUA to get around that, in which case you basically perform the same trick: write out your word in illustrator/inkscape/any vector editor with good text support, import the entire localization as single glyph using a font editor or something like [TTX](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools), and then set up a GSUB rule that points to that single glyph, rather than to a new sequence, using a many-to-one GSUB rule:

```
...
報告書 -> {glyph id for the "Generate report" glyph in PUA}
...
```

And that should be it: exploiting OpenType to achieve localization without ever touching "real" code (aside from the code you write to automate the font generation process of course!)

And I can strongly recommend joining https://typedrawers.com to ask people for the actual implementation and tooling help with that - it's almost trivial in an application like Font Creator, it's certainly hardly a lot of work in something like Font Forge, but typedrawers is where all the typography engineers hang out, and you'll be far more likely to get detailed help than Stackoverflow.

Comment: That is an excellent answer, definitely +1 from me. Also, thanks a lot for the link to that community. I will probably treat them to a write-up of the horrors i'm perpetrating. However sadly in my case this method does not work, as the software using the font at the end doesn't seem to be willing to support lookups when i tried. There's also a slight issue (though this doesn't scuttle the entire idea) in that localization often requires different translations for identical strings. I'm also curious: What is the overlap problem?

Comment: And thanks for the voice towards Font Creator. Right now it's a bit out of my budget, but i have a question: How is the scripting support? Right now i use a simple parametrized python script in order to inject all the necessary character combinations into the font, and i only need to touch fontforge to generate the binary font file. (This means the script can do the work entirely without font forge needing to be running at all.)

Comment: localization is a hard job, having to deal with "I can't even change the number of bytes per string" sure as hell doesn't make it any easier. Also note that you can of course still mix GSUB with PUA, if it turns out that you need to custom tailor your localized strings to the available "physical" width.

Comment: Also, if you need scripting: always use python, either with Font Forge or with [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) (or both of course. Why limit yourself, pick the best tool for the invidual tasks and combine them for easy wins). There is literally no reason to do that in any paid software package, not even FontLab 6 or something =)

Comment: Forgot to respond to the overlap question: you literally mentioned it. Imagine your have two strings, `水曜日` and `散水`, and you wrote PUA alternatives for `水曜日` so that they spell `wed + nes + day`. You don't want that `水=wed` PUA in the second string. The same happens when you want to localize different strings with different localizations, but in that context the only true solution is to map strings to stringids instead and _actually_ replace them with those in the application. And then use GSUB rules to map each string id to its actual string )or PUA fallback glyph).

Comment: Mixing them does indeed sound like a useful approach, but as mentoned, the software i'm translating doesn't seem to honor GSUB. As for scripting: Your answer sounds like it won't be particularly easy to adjust my python script to font creator. And thanks for answering the overlapping issue. Your solution is already roughly what i do. This is the font as i currently have it: https://i.imgur.com/DvSntap.png And before modifying the strings in the software i replace character pairs in the translation with characters that have the ordinal of the matching pair in the font.

Comment: Hm, did you remember to make sure the font is set to "GSUB is enabled by default"? Because most fonts with GSUB rules don't, they leave it up to the user to toggle the relevant opentype features instead, which we don't want in this case. Also with regards to Font Creator: it's a nice tool but my first recommendation would be "use FontForge", which has been the defacto powerhouse free solution for the last... well, forever, really. It's always been around, always been free, and is more powerful than most commercial software. Just "not as pretty".